# Why remain all floats the same memory size in python?

Tags: python, memory, floating-point, size

No matter what float I create, it always remain the same memory size of 24 byte. If I learned from my last post than 16 byte are the object itself and 8 bytes (64 bits) are used to save the information/number. The max and min floats can be accessed with `sys.float_info.max`/`sys.float_info.min` (1.79...e+308, 2.22...e-308). These numbers are far from what a "normal" 8 byte integer can get (2^63 - 1).
How does float work in binary and why does it always take 24 byte no matter what.

Comment: See [the floating point article on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic), because your question basically boils down to "what are floating point numbers". The **tl;dr** is that the "digits" (in reality: significand) and the "magnitude" (in reality: the exponent) are stored separately, allowing for a much wider range of representible numbers, with the drawback of not being able to represent every number in that range.

Comment: Another link to see: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/215065/can-anyone-explain-representation-of-float-in-memory

Comment: Thanks. Solved my "problem".